# What kind of knife could this be?

Tags: identification, weapons, spain

[image]

I recently found this knife/dagger, have no clue what type it is and what it was used for, there is a thumb hole I suspect on the spine as well as it looks to be “IMT” or “IMI” logo stamped on the side. It is also not very sharp at all I’m not sure because of intention or because of old age? Any ideas on what type of knife this is and what it could have been used for would help!

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't really seem like a historical object, but for identification questions please provide photos of the object in a well lit area from all sides and supply measurements. You say there's a logo - show us a close up of it.

Comment: As a detail, it's a bayonet —the "thumb hole" is for the barrel of a rifle. It also explains the strange shape of the blade and the handle.

Comment: @AlbertoYagos Yeah, had a good chuckle at "thumb hole"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Got it, is a Spanish M1969 Bayonet, check it here: https://www.preferredarms.com/weapons/daggers.php

[image]

Comment: The give away for this being a bayonet is what Will describes as "thumb hole". That kind of circular ring, perpendicular to the end of the hilt is a dead give away that it's designed to fit a gun (how would you hold it so your thumb goes though it?). I presume there's also a slot running along the top of the hilt that fits the gun? That's the second give away.